# How to set top and bottom margins of the Flutter Chip widget to zero?

Tags: flutter, widget, margin

How can I set the top and bottom margins of the Flutter Chip widget to zero?

So I can get this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Comment: Use sizebox between them did you try ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

set `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` in `Chip` widget.

**Example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            for(final i in List.generate(20, (i) => i))
            Chip(
              avatar: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              label: Text("Chip $i"),
              deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 'deleteIcon' is not displayed in chip. any suggestion?

Comment: Got it. Do not forget to add "deleteIconColor" and "onDeleted" attributes if you use deleteIcon property in Chip. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to further reduce vertical padding, you can do `visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact`.

Answer (score 7):

As the accepted answer suggests, setting `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` and place the `Chip` list inside `Wrap` will discard not only top and bottom margin but also left and right margin.

So if someone wants to give some margin between two Chips he can use `spacing` inside `Wrap`

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 3.0, // spacing between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 0.0, // spacing between lines
  children: [
    Chip(
      label: Text("Chip 1"),   
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    ),
    Chip(         
      label: Text("Chip 2"),       
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    ),
     ......
     ......
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to reduce the margins of you `Chip`

```
Chip(
  ... your other props    
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact      
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Use this or labelPadding but not both
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12) // You can reduce the font size for a smaller chip
)
```